# Reactjs: Alternative of always using 'npm start'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all I'd like to say that i'm really new to Reactjs and even javascript and I appreciate every little bit of help. We have a school project going on where we are using socket.io. 
In the [socket.io tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) you send an html page to the client using:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); });
```

That made sense for me, but when I started reading about react and watched some video's that also use socket.io in their react projects, I noticed that instead of sending the html page with the above function, they just ran *npm start* on the command line.

This renders your components on a certain port, while your express server is still running on another port. So now, instead of surfing to the port where your server is running on, you have to go to a different one, where react is loaded.

I'm wondering if there's any way (like the socket-io tutorial) to send the component that needs to be rendered to the client. So that you are only using one port, instead of running *npm start* and using 2 ports.

I don't know if that made any sense to you, and my wording of this problem is probably really bad, so 
thanks a lot for reading :D.

Comment: A server can serve the built static files of a React application. `npm start` is just a script that starts a development server with a lot of tools around it to ease development.

Comment: So what, specifically, can I do for example?

Comment: And I'm guessing a lot here since this is dependent on how your project is configured. Continue reading and doing tutorials, you're clearly on the right track but there's a lot more to learn and your question is kind of too broad/unclear for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) is quite complete and starts slowly.

Comment: Keep in mind that asking for off-site resources like tutorials, books, etc is off-topic on Stack Overflow. :(

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply

Comment: create-react-app and most other react development will have commands like `npm run build` that spit out a folder with your assets / index.html file etc